# How to remap "Go to definition" and "Rename all instances" on ZeroBrane Studio?

Tags: lua, ide, keymapping, zerobrane

I'm using ZeroBrane Studio 1.30

Is there any way to remap the Ctrl/Cmd-DoubleClick shortcut to something on the keyboard, like Ctrl-R? (Without the mouse click) on the user preferences?

At the same time, is there a way to remap the "Go to definition" shortcut to something else than Ctrl/Cmd+Alt+Click.

I already tried these with no luck:

`keymap[ID.RENAMEALLINSTANCES] = "Ctrl-R"`

`editor.keymap[#editor.keymap + 1] = {('R'):byte(), wxstc.wxSTC_SCMOD_CTRL, ID.RENAMEALLINSTANCES}`

Also instead of `ID.RENAMEALLINSTANCES` I've tried `ID_RENAMEALLINSTANCES` with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in 1.30 (which is the currently released version). This functionality has [already been added](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/597) and will be available in the next release (or you can use the current master branch).